# How to make button text bold?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have the text on my dynamicly added buttons bold. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
var b = new Button()
{
    Location = new Point(x * 30, y * 30),
    Width = 30,
    Height = 30,
    Tag = new Point(y, x), // game location x, y
    BackColor = Color.SkyBlue,
};
```

Comment: what kind of application u have ? is it WPF or WinForm or web app ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Windows Forms:

```
var b = new Button()
{
    Location = new Point(x * 30, y * 30),
    //...
};
b.Font = new Font(b.Font.Name, b.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
```

### WPF:

```
var b = new Button()
{
    Location = new Point(x * 30, y * 30),
    //...
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
};
```

### ASP.NET

```
var b = new Button()
{
    Location = new Point(x * 30, y * 30),
    //...
};
b.Font.Bold = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the last line of this code:

```
var b = new Button()
{
    Location = new Point(x * 30, y * 30),
    Width = 30,
    Height = 30,
    Tag = new Point(y, x), // game location x, y
    BackColor = Color.SkyBlue,
    Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8.25F, FontStyle.Bold)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic format for this in visual basic would be:

`btn.Font = New Font("Font Name", Font Size, FontStyle.Bold)`